# Testfor dropped items minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So I tried this command:

```
/testfor @e[x=445,y=88,z=216,r=3][type=Item] {Item:{id:minecraft:egg}
```

But it did the "invalid entity UUID" error and didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You closed the selector's parameters and opened them again, breaking selector syntax. You need to include all parameters within the same set of square brackets. You've also not completely closed the NBT data, just missing a final closing curly bracket. Fixed:

```
/testfor @e[x=445,y=88,z=216,r=3,type=Item] {Item:{id:"minecraft:egg"}}
```

Comment: it still says it isnt working?

Comment: @crazy_angel If the "invalid UUID" error occurs when the syntax is correct, that means no target was found. You simply do not have an item entity within 3 blocks of the specified coordinates. Ensure the coordinates are correct and there is an item entity to find.